# Troubles with Implementation of self written Module for Joomla and Auto Suggest function which should be in Javascript

Tags: php, module, javascript

I am trying to find a way to implement either a self written module in Joomla with PHP code of an dictionary or try to use the dictionary by putting the PHP code in a joomla article with sourcerer plugin. I am really new in Joomla and PHP. Could someone help?

1. How could I add a Javascript Code in order to get an AutoSuggest Function as a dropdown list to get suggestions for words when I start typing?
2. How to get this code into Joola files and install it as module?

I am trying this since days and can't go further. Here is the code which I wrote until now:

> {source}
>
>
> Dictionary
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
>
> <style>
> body {
> font-family: Arial;
> }
>
> * {
> box-sizing: border-box;
> }
>
> form.example input[type=text]  {
> padding: 10px;
> font-size: 17px;
> border: 1px solid grey;
> float: left;
> width: 80%;
> background: #f1f1f1;
>
> border-radius: 4px;
> }
>
> form.example button {
>
> border-radius: 4px;
> float: left;
> width: 20%;
> padding: 3.6px;
> background: #17558c
> ;
> color: white;
> font-size: 17px;
> border: 1px solid grey;
> border-left: none;
> cursor: pointer;
> }
>
> form.example button:hover {
> background: #0b7dda;
> }
>
> form.example::after {
> content: "";
> clear: both;
> display: table;
> }     
>
> body {
> }
>
> $brand-primary: #09c;
> $brand-gray: #ccc;
>
> .menubar {
> height: 230px;
> width: 100%;
> border: 1px solid $brand-gray;
> }     
>
> .panel {
> border-radius: 6px;
> box-shadow: none;
> background-color: $brand-primary;
> }
>
> .panel .panel-heading {
> padding: 1px 12px;
> }
>
> .panel .panel-body {
> background-color: white;
> border-radius: 6px;
> margin: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
> min-height: 200px;
> }
>
> p.ex1 {
> padding-left: 10px;
> }
>
> p.ex2 {
> padding-left: 20px;
> }
>
> </style>
>
>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <form class="example"  style="margin:auto;max-width:300px" method = "post">
>
> <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" >
>
>    <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
>
> </form>
>
> </body>
> </html>
>
> <?php
>
>
> $con = new PDO("mysql:testhosting;dbname=testdb",'testuser','testpassword');
>
>
> if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
> $str = $_POST["search"];
> $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE wort = '$str'");
>
> $sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
> $sth -> execute();
>
> if($row = $sth->fetch())
> {
> ?>
>
> <br> <br>   
>
> <div class="container"> 
> <div class="panel panel-primary"> 
>
> <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b><?php echo $row->wort;?></b></h4> 
> </div>
>
> <div class="panel-body"><h5><b><i><?php echo $row->form2;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->form3;?></i></b></h5></p> 
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz1;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz2;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz3;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz4;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz5;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz6;?>    
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz7;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz8;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz9;?>
>
> <?php echo $row->uebersetz10;?>
>
> </div>
> </div>
>
> </div>  
>
> </p>     
>
> <?php
>
> }
> else{
>
>
> echo "<br> The searched word is not given in our database.";
> }
> }
> ?>  
>  {/source}
> ```

Thank you in advance for your support and sorry for the long text!

Comment: Yes, as you admitted, your code is suffering from your inexperience. But hey, we all have to start from somewhere.  Some basic pieces of advice: 1. Your query is insecure/unstable because the user can post whatever value they want and malicious actors may be able to do bad things without thorough validation and sanitisation in place 2.  `<tr>` tags may only live inside `<table>` tags.  You will need to read some basic tutorials on html.  PHP is more difficult than HTML,  but you need to keep building your knowledge as quickly as you can to avoid frustration.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 1. Do you mean I have to put a variable for the search field in order to define a datatype? 2. Ok I deleted the <tr> tags. Could you please give some more advice how to fix the actual problem with auto suggestion and implementation of the module?

Comment: A prepared statement should contain placeholders (named or `?`) and then values bound to the variable before/during execution.  I don't think that I am the best person to answer your question, I'll leave it to others.

Comment: Is here nobody who could help out in this issue?

Comment: There may or may not be.  Some people don't have the patience to read long questions.  Some people lack the expertise.  Some people who have the expertise only visit once every few days.  Please remember that this is a 100% volunteer, 100% free community.  The responsibility is on the asker to create a clear, narrow question.  If you are needing immediate support and cannot afford to wait, you may wish to pay a professional Joomla developer to help you.  That said, please [edit] your question if you make progress.  If you completely resolve, please post an answer.